# Change CHART source link in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document in word with tables and charts linked to excel.
I need to change the link of these once in a month.
when i run the below link, tables source is changed to the new file, but the source link of the chart remain the same and doesn't change.
Here the code:

```
Sub Replace_Link()
Dim fieldCount As Integer, x As Long
With ActiveDocument
fieldCount = .Fields.Count
For x = 1 To fieldCount
With .Fields(x)
    Debug.Print .LinkFormat.SourceFullName;
    .LinkFormat.SourceFullName = "Q:\LINKNEWFILE"
    .Update
    .LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = False
    DoEvents
End With
Next x
End With
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: This code should update the chart, as well? What does the field code for the chart look like? I assume the actual file name used is more complete than what is visible in the code... (with a file extension, for example)? Are the only field codes in the document linked OLE objects?

Answer (score 2):

Try processing the tables & charts as shapes and inlineshapes:

```
Sub Replace_Links()
Dim x As Long: Const StrLnk As String = "Q:\LINKNEWFILE"
With ActiveDocument
  For x = .Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Shapes(x)
      If Not .LinkFormat Is Nothing Then
        With .LinkFormat
          .SourceFullName = StrLnk
          .Update
          .AutoUpdate = False
        End With
      End If
    End With
  Next x
  For x = .InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .InlineShapes(x)
      If Not .LinkFormat Is Nothing Then
        With .LinkFormat
          .SourceFullName = StrLnk
          .Update
          .AutoUpdate = False
        End With
      End If
    End With
  Next x
End With
End Sub
```